# ActionMailer and development mode, can it write to a file or something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to test my registration process locally (development mode), how can I test how emails will be sent out and rendered etc?

I am not referring to a unit-test or integration test, but just while developing my app and going on the register page etc. I want it to send out the emails but to a file not using smtp.

Is this possible?

What options do I have?

Answer (score 52):

This is configurable in the `config/environments/*.rb` files.

```rb
# output to tmp/mails directory
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file
# ... and to specify output location
# config.action_mailer.file_settings = { :location => Rails.root.join('tmp/mail') }
```

Detailed information can be found in the [config section](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration) of [Action Mailer Basics](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) or on [ActionMailer::Base API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base)

---

Rails 4.2 `:file` [delivery method source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb#L31) and [Mail::FileDelivery source](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/file_delivery.rb)

Comment: +1  wasn't aware of that option & could certainly use it myself.

Comment: don't forget to restart your server after making config changes. ;)

Comment: The "more information" is almost empty in terms of explaining the file option.

Comment: I found this page to be more informative on using :file http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Answer (score 8):

[LetterOpener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) makes it even simpler for you to preview the emails you just sent by opening the file in the browser automatically (in development environment of course).

Comment: not working for me on Rails 4. I wish their Readme had more info or pointed towards a tutorial for rails 4. seems like a cool thing but the documentation for new users is not great

Comment: works for one-off testing that an email was sent, yet I might recommend [mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher#rvm) for long-term testing

Answer (score 0):

I realize you said you want to check emails in the context of manual testing, but it seems worth mentioning that these sorts of tests can be automated. [email_spec](https://github.com/email-spec/email-spec) is one gem i've used to do it.