# How to setup mail on development with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actionmailer

I downloaded a project from github that has a mailer when deployed to production, but on my own local copy the mailer doesn't work.  How do I setup mail locally for development so that I can test it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286009/actionmailer-and-development-mode-can-it-write-to-a-file-or-something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) gem by Ryan Bates

Comment: thanks, i liked this one the most from the answers provided.  I personally ended up using the answer in the duplicate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286009/actionmailer-and-development-mode-can-it-write-to-a-file-or-something as it didn't need me to install anything, but this would be my second option.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the MailCatcher gem https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a gem.

In:

```
config/environments/development.rb
```

Set

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file
end
```

Then look for the mails in

```
PROJECT_ROOT/tmp/mails/email@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this when testing email during local development. Hope this helps

http://papercut.codeplex.com/